# Tfs Query to retrieve a particular type of WorkItems that is linked with a given list of other WorkItems

Tags: tfs, workitem

So I have a a list of tfs work items of one particular type ("Test Case") and I want to find all work items of another type ("Review) that are linked to at least one of the ones of the first list.

How would I go about and define such a query (or a number of queries.. but if multiple are necessary, obviously the fewer the better)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your query with the clause for `Work Item Type` of `Test Case`.

Change the `Type of Query` to `Work Items and Direct Links`, then in the second Filter control set the clauses you want for the linked work items.

It should look something like this (taken from Dev11 but pretty much the same in VS2010):

[image: TFS Query]

Comment: Dave, I forgot to mention that I was looking for the actual WIQL statement BUT your suggestion made me reaelize/remember I can save the query as a .wiql/xml file and see the actual query statement in there. Thanks for the hint/suggestion!